# how to change the value of table cells with a slider in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this project, there is a table in it, i want to be able to change the numeric values of the cells with the use of a slider.
Example: when the slider is set to 10, the values of the cells with numbers in them should change to the value already entered + 10, or any value that the slider is on. The sells with non-US text should stay as the are.
I can't seem to be able to write a function that takes the value of the slider and add that value to the table cells.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Другата Слънчева Система</title>
    
    <!-- Зареждане на библиотеката и стиловете -->
    <script src="suica.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Solar.css">
    
    <!-- основен код -->
    <script>
        
    
        //главна функция, инициализира графичните обекти 
        function main()
        {
        
            //построяване на полето за рисуване
            p = new Suica();
            background([0,0,0.35]);
            //demo(1200,1,0.5);
            
            orbit = document.getElementById('orbit');
            var r = orbit;
            
            //построяване на слънцето
            star = sphere([0,0,0],30);
            star.image = new Suica.Image('2k_sun.jpg');
            star.image.scale = [1,1];
            star.light = true;

            //построяване на меркурий
            planet1 = sphere([0,0,0],6);
            circle([0,0,0],45).custom({mode:Suica.LINE});
            planet1.image = new Suica.Image('2k_mercury.jpg');
            planet1.image.scale = [1,1];
            
            //построяване на венера
            planet2 = sphere([0,0,0],8);
            circle([0,0,0],75).custom({mode:Suica.LINE});
            planet2.image = new Suica.Image('2k_venus_atmosphere.jpg');
            planet2.image.scale = [1,1];
            
            //построяване на земя
            planet3 = sphere([0,0,0],14);
            circle([0,0,0],130).custom({mode:Suica.LINE});
            planet3.image = new Suica.Image('2k_earth_daymap.jpg');
            planet3.image.scale = [1,1];
            
            //построяване на луната
            moon1 = sphere([0,0,0],6);
            moon1.image = new Suica.Image('2k_moon.jpg');
            moon1.image.scale = [1,1];
            
            //построяване ма марс
            planet4 = sphere([0,0,0],12);
            circle([0,0,0],190).custom({mode:Suica.LINE});
            planet4.image = new Suica.Image('2k_mars.jpg');
            planet4.image.scale = [1,1];
            
            //построяване на юпитер
            planet5 = sphere([0,0,0],25);
            circle([0,0,0],280).custom({mode:Suica.LINE});
            planet5.image = new Suica.Image('2k_jupiter.jpg');
            planet5.image.scale = [1,1];
            
            //построяване на сатурн
            planet6 = sphere([0,0,0],22);
            circle([0,0,0],340).custom({mode:Suica.LINE});
            planet6.image = new Suica.Image('2k_saturn.jpg');
            planet6.image.scale = [1,1];
            
            //построяване на уран
            planet7 = sphere([0,0,0],18);
            circle([0,0,0],400).custom({mode:Suica.LINE});
            planet7.image = new Suica.Image('2k_uranus.jpg');
            planet7.image.scale = [1,1];
            
            //построяване на нептун
            planet8 = sphere([0,0,0],16);
            circle([0,0,0],460).custom({mode:Suica.LINE});
            planet8.image = new Suica.Image('2k_neptune.jpg');
            planet8.image.scale = [1,1];
            
            
            p.nextFrame = loop;
            lookAt( [1500,0,900], [0,0,0], [0,0,1] );
        }
        //виж лекция 14 движение по дъга
        function loop()
        {
            t = Suica.time;

            planet1.center = [(45)*Math.cos(t*3,5),(45)*Math.sin(t*3,5),0];
            
            planet2.center = [75*Math.cos(t*2.5),75*Math.sin(t*2.5),0];
            
            planet3.center[1] = (130)*Math.sin(t*2);
            planet3.center[0] = (130)*Math.cos(t*2);
            
            moon1.center[0] = planet3.center[0] + 30*Math.cos(4*t);
            moon1.center[1] = planet3.center[1] + 30*Math.sin(4*t);
            
            planet4.center = [190*Math.cos(t*1.1),190*Math.sin(t*1.1),0];
            
            planet5.center = [280*Math.cos(t*0.8),280*Math.sin(t*0.8),0];
            
            planet6.center = [340*Math.cos(t*0.6),340*Math.sin(t*0.6),0];
            
            planet7.center = [400*Math.cos(t*0.4),400*Math.sin(t*0.4),0];
            
            planet8.center = [460*Math.cos(t*0.2),460*Math.sin(t*0.2),0];
        }
        //функция за проверка на отговора от задача 1
        function comp()
        {
            var n1 = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value);
            if (n1 > 4000 && n1 < 5000)
            {
                alert('Правилен отговор!');
                return true;
            }
            else
            { 
                alert('Грешен отговор!');
                return false;
            }
        }
        function show_value2(x)
        {
            document.getElementById("slider_value2").innerHTML=x;
        }
    
    </script>   
</head>

<body onload="main()">

    <!--Заглавие и подзаглавие --> 
    <h1>Другата слънчва система</h1>
    <h4>Пламен Николаев Велков, Матматика и Информатика задочно, Факултетен № 50449</h4>
    <br>
    
    <h3>
        Слънчевата система е съставена от астрономически обекти.В средата й се намира Слънето, а около него кръжат небесн тела.
        Те включват планетите, планети джуджета, спътници, астероиди, комете, междупланетарен прах и газ.Всички те включително и Слънето
        около което обикалят са се сформирали преди около 4,6 милярда години при разпадането на молекулярен облак.
        <br>
        Осемте планети заемат основната част от масата в слънчевата система. Те обикалят около Слънето в почти кръгови орбити, които лежат на приблизително една равнина - еклиптика.
        Планетите се разделят на два основни типа: газови гиганти и планети от земен тип. Вътрешните четири планети са по-малки и са от земен тип, предимно съставени от скали и метал.
        Външите четири планети са значилно по-големи от тип газови гиганти съставени предимно от водород и хелий.
        <br>
        Освен планетите и техните спътници в слънчевата система има и по-малки обекти. Те са концентрирани в две области: Първата е астероиден пояс който се намира между Марс и Юпитер, неговият състав е подобен на планетите от земн тип.
        Втората област се намира отвъд орбитата на Нептун - транснептунови обекти. Те са съставени предимно от замръзнали вода, метан и амоняк. Има пет транснептунови обекта които са имат необходимата маса, за да бъдат заобиколени от собствена гравитация.
        Те се квалифицират като планети джуджета: Церера, Плутон, Хаумея, Макемаке и Ерида. 
        Шест от планетите и три планети джуджета имат естествени спътници, а външните планети имат и пръстени съставени от прах и други частици.
        <br>
        За измерване на разстоянието между обекти в слънчвата система е приета астрономическа единица(съкратено AU, от astronomical unit) със стойност средното разстоянието между Слънцето и Земята(приблизително 150 мил. километра).
        Меркурий е най-близко до Слънцето(0,387AU), а най-далечната планета е Нептун(30,068 AU).
    </h3>
    <!-- --> 
        
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        Орбитална обикола:<span id="slider_value2" style="color:black;font-weight:bold;"></span><br>
        <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" step="10" name="slide" value="0" onchange="show_value2(this.value)"> 
    </div>
    
    <canvas width="1000" height="600" style="border: solid 1px Black;">
    
    </canvas>
    
    <br>
    <br>
    <h5>
        На този етап единствената, известна на астрономията, планетата на която има живот е Земята. Намира се в така наречената обитаема зана на слънчевата система.
        В астрономията и астробиологията обитаема зона е област около звезда, в която на повърхността на дадена планета може да има течна вода и достатъчно силно атмосферно налягане. 
        Областта в която тази зона е базирана на разположението на Земята в слънчевата система и също така количеството лъчиста енергия, която тя получава от Слънцето.
        Обитаемата зана е разлина във всяка слънчева система, понеже звездата намираща се в центъра на дадена слънчва система е различна от Слънцето. Има слънца които горят с много по-голяма температута
        от нашето и такива с по-ниска температура, която е определящо за обитаемата зона на разглежданата слънчева система.
        Понеже течната вода е основополагаща за живот на нашета планета, дори и малки промени в температурана на повърхността могат да имат катастрофален ефект върху биосферата. 
        С напредването на науката можем да добием представа какви биха били тези променте ако орбитата на Земята се измени от настоящата.
    </h5>
    <!-- Tаблица с имперични данни за слънчвата система, необходима за решаване на задачи --> 
    <table border = "1">
                
            <tr>
                <th>Планета </th>
                <th>Орбитален обикколка (AU) </th>
                <th>Средна температура на повърхността(C<sup>o</sup>) </th>
                <th>Орбитален период (дни) </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Меркурий</td>
                <td>2,406</td>
                <td>166,85</td>
                <td>87</td>
            <tr/>
            <tr>
                <td>Венера</td>
                <td>4,545</td>
                <td>463,85</td>
                <td>244</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Земя</td>
                <td>6,283</td>
                <td>13,85</td>
                <td>365</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Марс</td>
                <td>9,553</td>
                <td>-63,15</td>
                <td>686</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Юпитер</td>
                <td>32,675</td>
                <td>-120,15</td>
                <td>4335</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Сатурн</td>
                <td>59,879</td>
                <td>-130,15</td>
                <td>10,757</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Уран</td>
                <td>120,515</td>
                <td>-205,15</td>
                <td>30,708</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Нептун</td>
                <td>188,925</td>
                <td>-220,15</td>
                <td>60,224</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    
    <h6>Задача 1: С помоща на интерактивния модел на слънчевата система и таблицата, намерете с колко стандартни астрономически единици(AU) трябва да се доближи Земята,
            за да започнат да кипят океаните на повърхносста?
        <input type="text" id="num1" value="" size="10"> AU
        <button onclick="comp()">Провери</button></h6>
    <noscript>
    
    </noscript>
    

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

here is a simple implementation using pure Javascript.

```
function changeTRdata(numberChange){
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
   for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     //iterate through columns
     //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
     if(j==2){
      let updateVal = [];
      col_arr = col.innerText.split(',');
      col_arr.forEach(function(numb){updateVal.push(numberFormat(Number(numb)+numberChange,','))})
      col.innerText = updateVal.join();
     
      }
      else
      {
     var cellVal = col.innerText.replace(',','');
     if(!isNaN(cellVal)){
    
     cellVal = Number(cellVal) +numberChange;
         col.innerText = numberFormat(cellVal,',');
     }
     
     }
   }  
}
        }
function numberFormat(_number, _sep) {
    _number = typeof _number != "undefined" ? _number : "";
    _number = _number.toString();
    _number = _number.replace(new RegExp("^(\\d{" + (_number.length%3? _number.length%3:0) + "})(\\d{3})", "g"), "$1 $2").replace(/(\d{3})+?/gi, "$1 ").trim();
    if(typeof _sep != "undefined" && _sep != " ") {
        _number = _number.replace(/\s/g, _sep);
    }
    return _number;
}
function show_value2(x)
        {
        let oldval =document.getElementById("slider_value2").innerHTML;
        let change = Number(x)-Number(oldval);
       
        changeTRdata(change)
        document.getElementById("slider_value2").innerHTML=x;
        }
```

here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/07obuqns/1/)